# How to load olympics.csv file in spyder?

Tags: pandas

i am writing `df=pd.read_csv('olmypics.csv')` and i am getting in response ' `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File olympics.csv does not exist: 'olympics.csv'`

Comment: Are you sure its not just the wrong spelling? olmypics vs olympics

Comment: If the file is located in certain path you also need to specify it, for example if it's in the documents folder: `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\your_user\Documents\olympics.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue with your spelling which is olympics. Therefore, it should be:

df = pd.read_csv(r'olympics.csv')

if you have different file path, you may use something like this:

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Doc\olympics.csv')